# Custom RazorViewEngine not works properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razorengine

I have separate dll with controllers and views (with usual folder structure). Here is my custom view engine:

```
public class SettingsViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public SettingsViewEngine()
    {
        //if I commit this nothing changes
        MasterLocationFormats = new[]
        {
            "~/bin/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/bin/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
        };
        
        ViewLocationFormats = new[]
        {
            "~/bin/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", //if I commit this line it starts look at 
                                          //at shared folder.Looks like only first
                                          //line of ViewLocationFormats  array used always.
            "~/bin/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
        };
    }
}
```

-- views are copied to bin folder.Without Layout property all works ok. But when set it I got error it cant be found at

```
"~/bin/Views/MyLayout.cshtml"
```

Any idea? Thanks.

**Update**

I have update my search engine with next ovveride:

```
    protected override IView CreateView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string masterPath)
    {
        // "~/bin/Views/Shared/_SettingsManagerLayout.cshtml" works (able find)
        return base.CreateView(controllerContext, viewPath, masterPath);
    }
```

while debug I was able to see that master is empty string.If I pass path directly I got strange error from layout -

> System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and the best extension method overload
>
> System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string, object)' has some invalid arguments

Here is how looks my view:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
@{
    Layout="_SettingsManagerLayout.cshtml";
}

...
```

**Update**

Some thoughts: I have error -

> The layout page "_SettingsManagerLayout.cshtml" could not be found at the following path: "~/bin/Views/Settings/_SettingsManagerLayout.cshtml"

But I expect that view engine will check several path specified in MasterLocationFormats (ViewLocationFormats), which is done for controllers views from root project with the same view engine.

**End Diagnose**

Custom view engine ignores MasterLocationFormats and used only first item from ViewLocationFormats.

Comment: How are you setting the layout in the _ViewStart.cshtml file? Something like `Layout = "~/bin/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";`?

Comment: no. without bin prefix.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting Layout in your view explicitly

```
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
```

~ is translated by virtual path provider into root of your web application - no engine comes into play with that.

What will work is either specify correct absolute path like this:

```
Layout = "~/bin/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
```

Or specify relative path from your view to your layout view like:

```
Layout = "../Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
```